# Issue in deploying Vapor 3 beta app to Heroku using Swift 4.1

Tags: swift, heroku, vapor

I am trying to deploy a new vapor app build using Vapor 3 beta and Swift 4.1 to Heroku but there is a constant failure in building. I tried adding `.swift-version` file with `4.1` in it, but no luck.

Also tried setting a new build pack using 
`$ heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/vapor-community/heroku-buildpack.git`

```
$ vapor --version
Vapor Toolbox: 3.1.4
Vapor Framework: 3.0.0-beta.3.1.3`
```

These are logs I see in terminal

```
$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 50, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (40/40), done.
Writing objects: 100% (50/50), 12.55 KiB | 3.14 MiB/s, done.
Total 50 (delta 11), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Swift app detected
remote: -----> Installing clang 5.0.0
remote: -----> Installing swiftenv
remote: Cloning into 'swiftenv'...
remote: -----> Installing Swift 4.1
remote: We don't have build instructions for 4.1.
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Swift app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to serene-cliffs-74861.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/serene-cliffs-74861.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/serene-cliffs-74861.git'`
```

In my heroku App, I see the following build logs

```
-----> Swift app detected
-----> Installing clang 5.0.0
-----> Installing swiftenv
Cloning into 'swiftenv'...
-----> Installing Swift 4.1
We don't have build instructions for 4.1.
!     Push rejected, failed to compile Swift app.
!     Push failed`
```

Can someone please help me solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Swift 4.1 hasn't be released at the moment, you need specify a dev snapshot in your `.swift-version` file. E.g.:

`4.1-DEVELOPMENT-SNAPSHOT-2018-03-01-a`